# Will winter hats disappear after December

Tags: support

I am starting to like the whole winter hats thingy (trophy system), will this disappear after December or will it change into other trophy systems giving digital achievements according to day, season, events, etc..

Answer (score 7):

Yes it will - "the hats get put back in their boxes on January 4th!"

reference: http://winterba.sh/