# Suggestion - Earned hats should remain on profile?

Tags: discussion

I believe that the [hats are gone](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5633/will-winter-hats-disappear-after-december) ??
Today I opened my profile and noticed that the line declaring how many hats I've earned has disappeared..

As said on winterba.sh that they are available till 4th of jan.. I think that was applicable for hats as a whole.
However I suggest that the hats a user has earned should remain on his profile forever. That way one can show-off and they are kind a reputation goodies too..

How about that earning hats is now closed but **Hats once earned remains with the user foreveer**

Comment: See the main meta for this discussion:

- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159171/what-do-hats-get-me-after-january-4th

Comment: Noooooooooooooooo! Extra fancy face hair gone!

Comment: I started this on chat.. then i was suggested to put it on meta...  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7537437#7537437

Comment: even the winterba.sh FAQ says :: What happens after January 4th?

After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site. ... but they were our hard earned hats... i really want them back :'(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### They're gone like Santa Claus is. Move on.

> As said on winterba.sh that they are available till 4th of jan

This was clear from the very beginning. Really.

> they are kind a reputation goodies too..

Hmm, I tend to disagree on that. Hats were mostly based on reputation scores and a type of activity that is similar to badges.

> should remain on his profile forever

In your 'bio' section you could put a line there. Suggestions:

- > I've earned 12 hats in the Winterbash 2012/2013! Check it out [here](http://winterba.sh/leaderboard/askubuntu.com). Wish I could show them to you, but they're back in their boxes...
- [by iSeth](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=7532603#7532603):

  > I made a tar.bz2 with all my hats in it here: [...]
- [by jrg](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=7531936#7531936):

  > Screenshots of me wearing each of my hats: [...]

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but what you said was, i was already aware of.. i am simply giving a suggestion that the should remain on the profile.. not asking where they went ?? :)

Comment: @Z9iT If people would disagree with my answer and wanted them to stay too, they would have probably put another answer here (rather than upvoting it). You can do this too. If it outnumbers the votes on mine, well, you'd have point. Now we can't even compare the two.

Comment: I dont disagree with you my friend.. infact this question of mine is not even really a question but a suggestion that hats should remain on the profile which you moderators have power to do... hehe :)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the people here don't have the power to change this.  If you _really_ want this you should ask on [Meta Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?as=1) as it covers all of SE.